# .htaccess file location for OpenStack with Go

Tags: .htaccess, go, openshift

I'm using OpenShift, and I'd like to know where the .htaccess file should go with Go language (golang). I tried all locations with other languages, none of them worked.

**Edit:**

Yes, I created a **1 small gear** application with Go language cartridge. Everything default, so it's [***The Go Cartridge***](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/29-go-language)

Comment: Did you figure out how to redirect all traffic to https? That was your goal, right?

Comment: My goal was to handle subsubdomains. I didn't figure it out, so I changed to another service, where it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the [Go cartridge](https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-go-cart); as far as I know it the `.htaccess` file should be on the web server gear. Your web server should run on the primary gear but without any other info it's hard to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: If you mean the the directory where **app-deployments** and **app-root** directories are, I can't write into that directly.